# Resuming and Finishing the flow

Tags: apex, visualforce, flow, process-builder

Created a flow in the sandbox to capture a survey.

I have enabled the ability to Pause the flow and added the component to Home page.

All the screens for the flow is complete and when I test run below 2 issues are found. 
1. In the last screen I do not find the Finish Button. There is a record update after last screen. When I add a screen after record update It shows the finish screen But if click the previous button present there it moves to the first and create a new record.
Is there any possibility to finish without going on the previous screens

2. When I resume a Paused flow, after clicking on the last screen, instead of redirected to the Account page, the flow is restarting. Appreciate your help.

On pause going to first screen is normal functionality , Is there any modification that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

1. You last action in the flow is to update the record, so the finish page will not render. You can refresh the record page to see the change. If the finish is needed, may need restructure the flow.
2. Control your finish page, make a vf page embed flow:interview. Like this: . It will land you to the home page.

Comment: Thanks , After restructuring only . I have put a finish button after record button but then on click of previous button it restart the flow and create a record again. Also ,  Regarding the pause button functionality what can be done